# change kivy popup widget background in python

Tags: python, properties, kivy

I have a kivy program that has a ‘sqlite’ database containing details of a golf competition which displays information & warning messages via a  standard Pop-up function  - pop_mess()
For testing purposes I open an alternative ‘testing’ database in a function – set_test_db().  When this is done I would like to change the background colour of the pop-up to warn the user that the main database is not being used.

I have tried to do this  (code at end of 'set_test_db'). However although the routine retrieves the current background colour correctly it will not change it.

Can someone point me in the direction of a solution. The coding method works fine for changing the text properties of a widget. (similar questions usually refer to text properties). I have used both list & tuple for colour values.

In .ky file

```
<CustomPopup>:
    popup_message: popup_message
    size_hint: .98, .75
    id: popup_id
    title: "Casual and Ancient"
    title_align: 'center'
    title_color: 1,.5,.3,1
    BoxLayout:
        id: contentbox
        orientation: 'vertical'
        TextInput:
            id: popup_message
            color: .3,.4,1.0,1
            background_color: [.7,1.0,.2,1]
            text: "text message goes here"
            font_size: 16
            font_name: 'RobotoMono-Regular'

…..
CaaRoot:
<CaaRoot>:
    orientation: 'lr-tb'
    padding: 10
    etc
    ...
```

---

in main.py

(self = CaaRoot)
...

```
def pop_mess(self,message):
        p_up=CustomPopup()
        lab=p_up.ids['popup_message']
        lab.text=message
        p_up.open()
```

...

```
def set_test_db(self):
        # on button in CaaRoot
        # open test data base instead of real
        if self.db != None:
            print 'Cannot Open Test Data Base - already running'
        else:
    # open ‘test’ database
    # set background colour of popup to warn user.

        fn='/home/.... caatestdb.db
        self.op_db(fn)
        self.testing='TEST database'

        p_up=CustomPopup()
        lab=p_up.ids['popup_message']
        x=lab.background_color

        new_col=[.9,.3,.3,1]
        lab.background_color=new_col

        self.pop_mess('color set to : '+str(new_col)+ '  was : '+str(x))
```

the popup displays

> color set to : [0.9, 0.3, 0.3, 1]  was : [0.7, 1.0, 0.2, 1]

(with background still set to [0.7, 1.0, 0.2, 1])

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at  [kivymd](https://gitlab.com/kivymd/KivyMD), which solves issues like that very well. It is basically a very elegant template for kivy based on [Google's Material Design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html). 
For me it makes all the coloring stuff and appearance in general much easier, especially as I am not a designer but a programmer.

The Demo has also a very complete sets of examples including popups.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I cloned 'md' and tried to run the 'kitchen sink' demo but failed with  'ImportError: No module named recycleview
' and  'Unable to import package 'kivymd.menu.MDDropdownMenu' I think I'm rather out of my depth with certain aspects of kivy although it does what I need it to.

Comment: RecycleView is very new in the Kivy libraries, you might need to download the version from Kivy-Garden. Have a look there are a few other nice Widgets too. An other possibility would be to clone the 1.9.2-dev. Look at [link](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html) recycleview was added in the version 1.10

Answer (score -1):

On further investigation of my problem I came across the similar question (Changing Background of Kivy Popup )

The fact that the solution given to that was “non-intuitive” involving the properties of the ‘inherited’ Canvas element(?) made me realise (remember ?) than some widgets do not have the full range of modifiable properties.

The 'background_color' property that I was retrieving was a property inherited from the Canvas which cannot be easily changed.

I have avoided the problem by creating a ‘popup’ widget whenever I wish to use it rather than modifying an existing widget. I still cannot (simply) change the background_color of the popup but I can change the background color of the parent element so that the user’s eye immeditely sees something different. I can also change the text color when calling the popup message function.

```
def pop_mess(self,message,colour=(.9,.6,.9,1)):
    #
    # text color can ve overridden by the 'colour' parameter
    # self.backc can be set as required to set the  color behind the 
    #    popup depending on circumstances


popup=Popup(title='Casual & Ancient', \
        content=Label(text=message,color=colour,\
                      font_name = 'RobotoMono-Regular'),\
                size_hint=(.98,.75),background_color=self.backc)


    popup.open()
```

I'm not completely sure that the analysis is correct or that there may be some side-effects but it seems to work ok (and was somewhat simpler to code)